# Why do event handlers use Object Sender when being automatically created in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2013, eventhandler

For example if I had:

**Initialize Control**

```
MyControl mc = new MyControl();
mc.MouseUp += mc_MouseUp;
```

**Event Handler**

```
void mc_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //annoying cast...
    MyControl control = (MyControl)sender;

    //Do some stuff to MyControl
}
```

is it not implicit that `sender` will always be a `MyControl` object?

but yet the event handler

```
void mc_MouseUp(MyObject sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Gives an error:

> No Overload for mc_MouseDown matches delegate
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler

Why is this?

Comment: it's not implicit since you can invoke `mc_MouseUp` like `mc_MouseUp("Hello World!", null)` and it will compile perfectly well...

Comment: @stefankmitph That's a benefit - but is it why? ;)

Comment: That's because someone at Microsoft eventually has defined the MouseEventHandler delegate and so all mouse events have to match this delegate, otherwise it wouldn't be recognized as MouseEvent. Maybe that's a bad explanation... (then I'm sorry for it)

Comment: Also I have see some libraries (DotNetBar not to mention names) where the sender is actually none of the objects to which you registered. It was a _NavigationBar_ (list of buttons object, only one is checked at a  time), and its `CheckedButtonChanged` event. The sender was the button instead of the _NavigationBar_.

Comment: and one point is that you could use one event handler for multiple controls/senders...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the control that gets to decide on the signatures for its events (what delegates it wants to use), and *most* event signatures always use a first parameter called `sender` of type `object`. That follows the [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229011%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> - The return type is [Void](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.void(v=vs.100).aspx).
> - The first parameter is named *sender* and is of type [Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.object(v=vs.100).aspx). This is the object that raised the event.
> - The second parameter is named *e* and is of type [EventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.eventargs(v=vs.100).aspx) or a derived class of [EventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.eventargs(v=vs.100).aspx).This is the event-specific data.

You can use the same handler code to listen to multiple events from multiple controls, of different types, so it wouldn't be necessarily good to restrict the sender type.

These guidelines made a lot more sense before [delegate variance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233060.aspx) was introduced in .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

> is it not implicit that sender will always be a MyControl object?

No. `mc_MouseUp` is simply a method defined which matches the delegate signature of `MouseUp`. It can be invoked inside of your class (if declared *private*) by any caller, which can pass an arbitrary `object`. If your derived type from `Control` decides to send `FooBar` as the object sender, he can do so.

> No Overload for mc_MouseDown matches delegate
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler
>
> Why is this?

The specification states:

> • For each value parameter (a parameter with no ref or out modifier),
>   an **identity conversion (§6.1.1)** or **implicit reference conversion
>   (§6.1.6)** exists from the parameter type in D to the corresponding
>   parameter type in M.

Since there isn't an identity or implicit reference conversion from `object` to `MyObject`, this doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

> > No Overload for mc_MouseDown matches delegate System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler

Because MouseEventHandler event handler is declared as

```
public delegate void MouseEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    MouseEventArgs e
)
```

You are required to refer same signature.

**Note**

If it was like this

```
public delegate void MouseEventHandler(
    MyObject sender,
    MouseEventArgs e
)
```

Then both the signature would have valid.

> My point is you can make scope big not small by specifying MyObject as first parameter instead of object.